# How to match key while pushing value into array in javascript

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to push a value after matching id value.

I have comments JSON which has property : `reply`

```
[{
        "id": "1",
        "root_id": "1",
        "target_id": "12",
        "text": "Hello World!",
        "comment_posted_by": "John",
        "comment_posted_by_image": "/../../assets/images/no-user.png",
        "comment_time": "2 mins ago",
        "reply": [{
                "id": "123",
                "root_id": "1",
                "target_id": "222",
                "text": "Nice!"
            },
            {
                "id": "124",
                "root_id": "1",
                "target_id": "222",
                "text": "Good!"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "root_id": "2",
        "target_id": "12",
        "text": "Hello RG!",
        "comment_posted_by": "John",
        "comment_posted_by_image": "/../../assets/images/no-user.png",
        "comment_time": "2 mins ago",
        "reply": [{
                "id": "123",
                "root_id": "1",
                "target_id": "222",
                "text": "Hey john how are you?"
            },
            {
                "id": "124",
                "root_id": "1",
                "target_id": "222",
                "text": "Hi john!"
            }
        ]
    }, {
        "id": "3",
        "root_id": "3",
        "target_id": "12",
        "text": "Thanks.",
        "comment_posted_by": "John",
        "comment_posted_by_image": "/../../assets/images/no-user.png",
        "comment_time": "2 mins ago"
    }, {
        "id": "4",
        "root_id": "4",
        "target_id": "12",
        "text": "Great.",
        "comment_posted_by": "John",
        "comment_posted_by_image": "/../../assets/images/no-user.png",
        "comment_time": "2 mins ago"
    },
    {
        "id": "5",
        "root_id": "5",
        "target_id": "12",
        "text": "Welcome.",
        "comment_posted_by": "John",
        "comment_posted_by_image": "/../../assets/images/no-user.png",
        "comment_time": "2 mins ago"
    }
]
```

**Comments** and their **Reply**
I want to push a reply on by using below HTML code:

**HTML**

```
<div [attr.commentId]="commentData.id" class="addReplyContainer replyTextAreaContainer" style="display: none" >
              <textarea  (keyup.enter)="addReply($event,commenData.root_id)" [(ngModel)]="reply" style="width:100%" class="replyText commentText addReplyTextarea form-control"></textarea>
            </div>
```

and want to push newly made reply json into array mentioned above:

```
var reply =
{
"id": "125",
"root_id":1,
"target_id":"222",
"text":"Great!"
}
```

Is there a way to do this using $.each?

I am trying below method but it is giving me error:

```
 addReply(event, root_id)
  {
    let commentDataa = this.commentsData;
    let replyy = this.reply;
    jQuery.each(this.commentsData, function (index, value) {


        if(value.root_id == root_id)
        {
          commentDataa.reply.push({
            root_id:root_id,
            target_id: "12",
            text: replyy,

          });

        }
    })

  }
```

> Error: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Any guidance would be appreciated.
Thanks in ADVANCE.

Comment: commentDataa is an array so commentDataa[index].reply.push() should work.

Comment: You are missing `index` in `commentDataa`

Comment: Thank you Everyone. Let me try this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to access the `index` of the `commentDataa` array so that you can push reply in that particular object of `commentDataa[index]` object.

```
addReply(event, root_id);
{
  let commentDataa = this.commentsData;
  let replyy = this.reply;
  jQuery.each(this.commentsData, function (index, value) {

    if (value.root_id == root_id)    {
      commentDataa[index].reply.push({
        root_id: root_id,
        target_id: '12',
        text: replyy
      });
    }
  });
}
```